# Can routes in Express be declared with a loop?

Tags: node.js, express

When I try to declare the below, the index page works, but the other pages all 404. I know it's not a problem with my links.js file, since when I hard code the output of the for loop, the links all work. I console.logged the router object and it shows the info in the stack. But when I try to open any of the links, they 404, and nothing is logged to the console.

Is it not possible to declare routes using a for loop? Code is copied below.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var config = require('../models/config.js');
var links = require('../models/links.js');

// homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: config.title });
});

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    router.get(links[i].regex, function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("trying to open " + links[i].url);
        res.render(links[i].url, { title: links[i].title, link: links[i] });
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a proper closure around the current value of `links[i]`. By the time your routes get called, `i === links.length`, so `links[i]` points to something other than what you expect.

The easiest way around this is to simply use `links.forEach()` instead, which creates/uses a closure:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  router.get(link.regex, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("trying to open " + link.url);
    res.render(link.url, { title: link.title, link: link });
  });
});
```

Comment: `forEach()` and a `for`-loop are different as I noted in my answer. If your route handlers were called you would see the difference in the output. Anyway, if your route handlers are not getting called, you should (double) check your `.regex` values.